# Jenkins Build Python Project

Tags: python, jenkins

I need to set up a Jenkins server to build a python project. But I can't find any good tutorials online to do this, most of what I see uses pip, but our project simply works on

```
python.exe setup.py build
```

I've tried running it as a Windows Batch file setting it up through the configure options in Jenkins, where I enter the above line in the box provided, but the build fails.
When I try to run this I get a build error telling me there is no cmd file or program in my project's workspace. But it seems to me that cmd would be a program inherent to Jenkins itself in this case.

What's the best way to go about setting up Jenkins to build a python project using setup.py?

Answer (score 0):

Really i used jenkins to test Java EE project and i don't khnow if it will be the same principle or not , 
so i downloaded the jenkins.war from the website and i deployed it on my jboss server and I reached it via an url on the browser : http://localhost:serverport/jenkins the i created a job and i select the server & jdk & maven & the location of my project in workspace then i make a run to build the project.
I am sorry if you find  that my subject is far from your demand but I tried  to give you a visibility onto my use.

Answer (score 0):

I relaized I did something stupid and forgot that my coworker had set it up on a UNIX server, so I should have been using the shell instead of Windows Batch. Once I changed that and installed the python plugin, I got it to build fine.